# Angular routing - resolve or onEnter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My use case is very simple and i'm sure many apps share the same one. I need to verify user and need a simple url to retrieve user token from URL, make api call to my backend service and route the user according to the result from the API.

I don't need to render any page but just make API call and parse the response. I see two options to accomplish: Resolve or OnEnter. I also think there might be another simple way.

Here are the steps:

1. user getting email with link to /verify?token={token}
2. in app.js I have a state 'verify' and URL '/verify=token'
3. call API and get "true" or "false"
4. if false, redirect user to homepage, if true redirect the user the user profile page.

What is the best and simple way to accomplish what I like to do?

Thanks.

btw - I'm using ui-router.

Comment: If it is authorization related I would use `resolve`...why enter something that user shouldn't have access to in first place?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you should use Resolve of ui-router to make sure state won't load until all data were resolved.

To make user feel good, you should show a loading indicator and register event $stateChangeSuccess to hide it once done